# How do I sort args into ascending order?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I am trying to sort 'args' into ascending order, what am I missing?
Whenever I put random arguments in the command line the first two will work, I get an array and a string. However, on the third one I want the array to be sorted into ascending order. The input is always 0.

I also tried to create my own algorithm but it dint' work.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class tri {

public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    if (args.length < 3) {
        System.out.println("Re-execute with at least 3 arguments");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("\n Printing as an array:");

    for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++)     //print each word 
        System.out.println(args[i]);

    String str = "";

    for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++) 
        str = str + args[i] + " ";          //concatenate into a string

    System.out.println("\n Printing as a string:");

    System.out.println(str);                //print the string


    System.out.println("\n Printing after sorting:");


     int [] sorted = new int[args.length];
     Arrays.sort(sorted);                   //sort the sorted array
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted));

    /*for (int i=0; i < args.length - 1; i++)  {
        System.out.print(args[i] + " ");  
    }*/
}
}
```

Output:

```
Printing as an array:
ball
cat
ship

Printing as a string;
ball cat ship

Printing after sorting;
[0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: `int [] sorted = new int[args.length];` here you just created an array of integers but did not assign any value to it. int has a default value of 0 which is being printed in the o/p. I'm not sure entirely what you're trying to do here, but apparently you have a string of arguments and want to sort them (maybe?). But then why use `int` ?

Comment: Yes, I have a string of arguments, and I did wanted to sort them. I shouldn't have used int. I also forgot about the value and somehow thought it would come from 'args'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're trying to do:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Tri {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.sort(args);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

As program arguments I entered `"abc" "efg" "abz"` and the output was

```
[abc, abz, efg]

Process finished with exit code 0
```